# Rainbow Scrolling Text Using <span>

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, text

I would like to turn a small paragraph into rainbow text, in which the colors scroll from right to left in an infinite loop using JavaScript. I currently have this paragraph:

```
<div id="rainbow">
  <p id="rtext">
    <span id="s1" style="color: red">H</span>
    <span id="s2" style="color: blue">e</span>
    <span id="s3" style="color: green">l</span>
    <span id="s4" style="color: purple">l</span>
    <span id="s5" style="color: orange">o</span>
    <span id="s6" style="color: magenta">!</span>
  </p>
</div>

<div id="actbtn">
    <button onclick="activ()">Click for RAINBOW!</button>
</div>`
```

I am fairly new to JavaScript so I am not sure how to write the `activ()` function to infinitely scroll the colors.

EDIT:
I would like to thank Ben for the looping script, but now I also need to know how to use the          `activ()` function to change the color of a `<span>` element. I have tried the following script:
    `function activ() {
    document.getElementById("s1").style.color = 'magenta';
}`
But the color will not change. I am trying to keep the script as simple as possible, but also make it work.

FINAL EDIT:
I used Ivan's "UPD Without JQuery" code and added a few colors, and this is what I end up with:

```
<script>
function EyeVommit() {
    document.getElementById("actbtn").style.display = 'none';
    'use strict';
    var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'purple', 'orange', 'magenta', 'chartreuse', 'cyan', 'yellow'],
        target = document.getElementById('rtext').children,
        i,
        len = colors.length,
        inter = setInterval(function() {
            colors.unshift(colors.pop());
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                target[i].style.color = colors[i];
            }
        }, 200);
}
</script>
<div id="table1">
<p id="rtext"> <span id="s1">H</span><span id="s2">e</span><span id="s3">l</span><span  id="s4">l</span><span id="s5">o</span><span id="s6">!</span>

    <br />
    <div id="actbtn">
        <button onclick="EyeVommit()">Pabam!</button>
    </div>
</p>
```

[The result.](http://jsfiddle.net/Wrw6A/)

Comment: What do you mean infinte scroll the colors? You want all the letters to keep changing colors?

Comment: @putvande I would like to make every span color change into the color to the left of that span, if that makes sense. Basically, I want the colors to change in an infinite sequence.

Comment: http://codepen.io/rlemon/pen/okxAJ I did this in canvas a couple weeks ago out of bordum

Comment: @rlemon I love that! Is there a way to make the colors start scrolling with an `onclick` script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm begging you, never, never, never use it in design

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Price</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script>
    function EyeVommit() {
        'use strict';
        var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'purple', 'orange', 'magenta'],
            $target = $('#rtext span'),
            counter,
            i,
            len = colors.length,
            inter;
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                $target[i] = $($target[i]);
            }
            inter = setInterval(function () {
                colors.unshift(colors.pop());
                for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    $target[i].css('color', colors[i]);
                }
            }, 200);
    }
</script>
<div id="table1">
    <p id="rtext">
        <span id="s1">H</span>
        <span id="s2">e</span>
        <span id="s3">l</span>
        <span id="s4">l</span>
        <span id="s5">o</span>
        <span id="s6">!</span>
    </p>
</div>
<script>
EyeVommit();
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

UPD without jQuery

```
<script>
    function EyeVommit() {
        'use strict';
        var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'purple', 'orange', 'magenta'],
            target = document.getElementById('rtext').children,
            i,
            len = colors.length,
            inter = setInterval(function () {
                colors.unshift(colors.pop());
                for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    target[i].style.color = colors[i];
                }
            }, 200);
    }
</script>
<div id="table1">
    <p id="rtext">
        <span id="s1">H</span><span id="s2">e</span><span id="s3">l</span><span id="s4">l</span><span id="s5">o</span><span id="s6">!</span>
        <button onclick="EyeVommit()">Pabam!</button>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Put all spans in one line. Browser interprets each newline as space.

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I didn't think of that. Works perfectly. However, I  do not want the text to start changing colors until the viewer presses a button.

Comment: See upd without jQuery with a button

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

If by "Infinitely scroll" you mean create an infinite loop, you could do this.

```
function blaah(blaah){
//This is where you put all of your rainbow-y code

blaah("blaah");
}
```

Then you can just call the event through your button.

This code works because everytime the function runs, you call it again. (Second-last line of the function.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that will work for any text that you put in the rtext block

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GtwxD

Here's the HTML

```
<div id="rainbow">
<p id="rtext">Hello! This is some rainbow text!</p>
</div>

<div id="actbtn">
<button>Click for RAINBOW!</button>
</div>
```

This is the Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  createSpans();
  $('#actbtn').click(activ);

});

$rtxt = $('#rtext');
var text = $rtxt.html() , color;

function createSpans(){
  $rtxt.html(' ');
  window.colorCount = 0;
  window.on = false;
  colorPicker();
}

function activ(){
  if(!window.on){
        window.id = setInterval(colorPicker,100);
    window.on = true;
  }
  else{
    clearInterval(window.id);
    window.on = false;
  }
}

function colorPicker(){
  $rtxt.html(' ');
  window.colorCount++;
  for(var letter = 0; letter < text.length; letter++){
    switch ((letter + colorCount) % 6){
        case 0 : 
        color = "red";
        break;
      case 1 : 
        color = "orange";
        break;
      case 2:
        color = "green";
        break;
      case 3 :
        color = "purple";
        break;
      case 4 :
        color = "blue";
        break;
      case 5 :
        color = "gold";
        break;
      default : 
        color = "black";
        break;
    }
    $rtxt.append('<span style=" color:' + color + ';">' + text[letter] + '</span>');
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. The text does not change colors and sits at black.

Comment: Oh and make sure to include jquery for this to work! <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>